# How to assign to base field?

Tags: f#

I have a base class with a field called 'Root'. I am trying to assign a value to it by using the following code inside the `do binding`

```
base.Root <- somevar
```

I am getting the following error

> error FS0419: 'base' values may only be used to make direct calls to the base implementations of overridden members

What am I missing? It is a field not property in the base class

Comment: Do you have a more complete example?

Comment: @TomasPetricek Yes this is my actual code, I am trying to implement a language using Irony (call me brave if you will). https://gist.github.com/fahadash/84edfbf38c74435ae0ef

Make sure to add Irony nuget package to your project

Comment: Here is the C# example that I am kinda re-writing in F# http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kirillosenkov/archive/2009/10/31/irony.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, F# compiler does not allow mutating a field of the base class via `base.` reference in derived class constructor; and the error message prompts you of valid `base.` keyword usages.

Nevertheless, you may try a nasty hack, for example by *upcasting* constructed derived instance as in a snippet below :

```
type FormulaGrammar() as self =
    inherit Grammar()
    do
        ... stuff from your gist here......
        (self :> Grammar).Root <- expr
```

Although after a brief peek into your C# prototype `irony.aspx` I'd say that similar part of constructor there uses not base `Grammar`, but derived type `ExpressionGrammar` for setting the `Root` field, which upon your code simply translates into `self.Root <- expr`.